# Django orm query fails in Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to perform a makeshift spatial join in django between 2 unrelated tables in a postgis database. An example query would be to locate points in one table within a certain distance of points in a second table.

the first query could be cafes found using the following query:

```
q1 = Pois.objects.filter(tags__amenity__contains = "cafe")
```

for the next query, I would like to use the 1st to return objects within a certain dist or ideally return only the distance between the closest objects. In sql this looks like:

```
select 
    stops.id,
    stops.the_geom as geom,
    min(dist/(1.3*60)) as wlk_time
from 
    ways_vertices_pgr stops, lateral (
        select 
            st_distance(st_transform(stops.the_geom, 4326)::geography, st_transform(p.geom, 4326)::geography, false) as dist
        from pois p
        where p.tags @> '{"sport":"soccer", "leisure":"pitch"}'::jsonb
    ) as dist
where dist < 400
group by stops.id, stops.the_geom;
```

In django orm, when using the manager.raw() to execute a facsimile query with the q1 as an insertion into the query, the function fails when attempting to pass the results of q1 into the second query.

Based on the documentation for the spatial queries, I need to pass the results of q1 or the q1.query string into the second query is a specific way but I am not sure how this is accomplished

[image]

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#spatial-queries

However it is unclear how this is performed for me.

Comment: can you please add the complere code of both qzeries